# The requested resource does not support http method 'T' (or 'ST') with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I've got a strange issue I'm running into. When running a series of HTTP requests with Alamofire I get the error response:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'T'

(the above was a GET request)

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: request.httpMethod, parameters: request.parameters, encoding: request.encoding, headers: request.headers).responseData { response in
```

When I debug and look into the value at request.httpMethod it is always the full GET, but I get that error regardless. I've tried following the deeper logic in Alamofire, but it seems to hold the value of GET as far as I can trace it through my pod.

I fired up Charles to listen to some http network traffic to see if its marked as `GET` or `T`, but traffic for that request doesn't show up at all...

I've repro'd the behavior on both simulator and device.

If I run the exact same http request, but using `urlSession.uploadTask`, it works fine and never hits the issue.

Anyone see this or have any ideas on how to identify what's causing the truncation? Best I can guess its happening in Alamofire, but I'm stumped as to where to go to from here.

Comment: Which encoding do you use? Try encoding: URLEncoding.default. Check whether the problem exist, if you use the Content-Type: application/json

Comment: This works... but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which encoding do you use?

Try encoding: `URLEncoding.default.`

Check whether the problem exist, if you use the `Content-Type: application/json`

The problem could be caused, if the backend is using spring. It seems to be a backend problem.

> Some people have problems with Alamofire, where Moya work instead,
>   some other people have problems with Moya, where Alamofire work.. It's
>   a strange issue, but again, I'm very sure, that the backend cause the
>   issue!

Comment: Our back-end isn't spring, but this did solve the issue. My only thought is the guilty endpoint that was having this issue was a GET request that didn't need JSONEncoding